# How to create a spinnable image for iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am really at a loss for starting this project.  I have an object that I want the user to be able to flick their finger and spin on an iPhone/iPad app that I am creating, but don't really know how to do it. As an example of what I am talking about, the Elements app allows you to "spin" the element.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The Elements uses OpenGL to present a 3D model. I suggest you look into OpenGL if you want a similar effect.

http://maniacdev.com/2009/04/8-great-resources-for-learning-iphone-opengl-es/

In the case of The Elements, it's not an image you're spinning, it's a 3D model.

Comment: I'm pretty sure The Elements doesn't use 3D model, but pre-rendered videos + custom scrubbing.

Answer (score 0):

This will spin something in a circle.  However, you'll have to handle your touch events for the flick

Where angle is a CGFloat and theView is a UIView

```
-(void)spinViewABit
{
  angle += 0.01;
  if (angle > 6.283) { 
    angle = 0;
  }

  CGAffineTransform transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
  theView.transform = transform;
}
```

Comment: What do I use as the 3D image that can be spun?